# Increasingly longer TTFB on Apache

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

A shared hosting with unknown hardware and configuration running on Apache:

[image]

A brand-new Apache 2.4.25-0.0+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 installed on Ubuntu 16.04 on a dedicated server:

[image]

How can I have assets loaded in parallel on the dedicated server? Apache seems to be misconfigured by default.

I should add that the screenshot is with http2 enabled. With http2 disabled the result is exactly the same but instead of long TTFB I have incrementally longer "stalled" status in Chrome's "Network" panel.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, on Apache the SPDY module that enables H2 protocol only supports 3.0 and not 3.1 - Chrome only supports 3.1+ now.

In essence using Nginx or NodeJS for example means you can use the later versions of SPDY, and enable these async features you speak of.

> It is also worth noting, if you enable the protocol column on DevTools you can see whether it is actually working.
>   [image]

Comment: I'm trying this with http/1.1 and http/2 and the result is the same: on a very bad shared hosting (php execution limited to 6h daily; very slow, WordPress execution takes 700ms for the homepage of the default theme) I get 3.7 seconds to download all assets and on a great dedicated server with Intel Xeon and a SSD (WordPress execution takes only 50ms for the homepage of the default theme) assets take 9.8 seconds to be downloaded. Something is clearly wrong and the problem is pictured. It's either increasingly longer TTFB or "stalled" status.

Comment: @Koam possible to provide a link so I can test it? Also try disabling all Wordpress plugins tmp so you can ensure that's not affecting it (always worth a shot).

Comment: Unfortunately, I would prefer to not provide the IP because it would remain here forever. This is a brand-new, not configured Apache on a brand-new Ubuntu 16.04. I didn't configure anything yet except for a virtual host for a domain and a letsencrypt SSL certificate (to enable http/2). It just was like this from the first second.

Comment: @Koam can you run your site on this and let me know what the results are (screenshot if possible) - [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)